# i need to return %appdata% path from txt file

Tags: codeigniter

this is my code
for /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('findstr /I "rr=" config.xml') do rmdir /s /q %%a

config.xml file
rr=%appdata%\1

the result
%appdata% print as text not back with full path

i need to back with full path

thanks for help

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.